# How to show a legend for a bar chart in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I am trying to show a simple bar chart, through canvas using jquery.
My code in the html.erb in my views is the following:

```
<script>
                var Script = function () {

                    var data = {


                        labels: ["<%= @label1%>", "<%= @label2%>","<%= @label3%>","<%= @label4%>", "<%= @label5%>"],

                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: "My First dataset",
                                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                                highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                                highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data: <%= @test_val %>
                            }
                        ]

                    };


                    new Chart(document.getElementById("bar").getContext("2d")).Bar(data);

                }();
            </script>
```

I use variables from the controller to import my labels and my data.
I would like to show a legend using this chart.

I tried many things: 
the legend template in options

```
 legendTemplate:  "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
```

However I got syntax errors for unexpected "(" or "{" etc.

I also tried the chartjs-ror, however again I can not display the legend.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste the following code in yours

**HTML**

```html
<div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
```

**JS**

```js
   document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = myChart.generateLegend();
```

```css
CSS

.chart-legend li span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Providing explanation with code is highly encouraged. Also, your snippet example appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
legendTemplate: <%= %Q{
      <ul class="#{name.toLowerCase()}-legend">
        #{for (var i=0; i < datasets.length; i++)}
          #{if (datasets[i].label)}
            <li>
              <span style="background-color: #{ datasets[i].strokeColor }"> </span>
              #{ datasets[i].label }
            </li>
          #{end}
        #{end}
      </ul>
  } %>
```

or even better by using `each`:

```
legendTemplate: <%= %Q{
      <ul class="#{name.toLowerCase()}-legend">
        #{datasets.each do |dataset|}
          #{if (dataset.label)}
            <li>
              <span style="background-color: #{ dataset.strokeColor }"> </span>
              #{ dataset.label }
            </li>
          #{end}
        #{end}
      </ul>
  } %>
```

Comment: adding this part of code, there are syntax problems which I cannot figure out.. :(

Comment: If you could provide the exactly how `legendTemplate` data should look then I might be able to help you. Also, what are the syntax problems you're facing?